# How to fix stock android without app lock installed in it?

Tags: android

How to intstall an app lock into android device so that it could not be deleted by others

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

You need to lead the user to make your application be a [device administrator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN)